# Python list manipulation for anagrams

Tags: python, list

I have a list which contains several lists with a lot of words (anagrams) from a given sentence.

```
anagrams_list = [['artist', 'strait', 'traits'], ['are', 'ear', 'era'], ['detail', 'dilate', 'tailed']]
```

I want to create a list that contains each sentence that I can create with these words.

Here it will be :

```
result = ['artist are detail', 'artist are dilate', 'artist are tailed', 'artist ear detail', ...]
```

I tried with a lot of for but depends on how many list I have in anagrams_list it's just impossible, and i guess recursive would be fine but i have no idea on how to create this.

Comment: `itertools.product` is perfect for this.

Comment: @PM2Ring: well some postprocessing needs to be done to create a list. But this is indeed the underlying function to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for that and do post processing by joining the tuple into a sentence:

```
import itertools

result = [' '.join(x) for x in itertools.product(*anagrams_list)]
```

this creates:

```
>>> result
['artist are detail', 'artist are dilate', 'artist are tailed', 'artist ear detail', 'artist ear dilate', 'artist ear tailed', 'artist era detail', 'artist era dilate', 'artist era tailed', 'strait are detail', 'strait are dilate', 'strait are tailed', 'strait ear detail', 'strait ear dilate', 'strait ear tailed', 'strait era detail', 'strait era dilate', 'strait era tailed', 'traits are detail', 'traits are dilate', 'traits are tailed', 'traits ear detail', 'traits ear dilate', 'traits ear tailed', 'traits era detail', 'traits era dilate', 'traits era tailed']
```

Comment: Great solution, Even after few years reading Q&A here, it still feels good to learn new stuff you never met before. Thanks :)

Comment: @omri_saadon: well that is basically why most people are hanging around here I think: to see new techniques to solve problems :) It is always nice to see other people doing clever things and use that in industry the next day :).

Answer (score 3):

A variation on the same theme as Willem's answer is to use `map`:

```
from itertools import product

anagrams_list = [
    ['artist', 'strait', 'traits'], 
    ['are', 'ear', 'era'], 
    ['detail', 'dilate', 'tailed']
]

result = list(map(' '.join, product(*anagrams_list)))
for s in result:
    print(repr(s))
```

**output**

```
'artist are detail'
'artist are dilate'
'artist are tailed'
'artist ear detail'
'artist ear dilate'
'artist ear tailed'
'artist era detail'
'artist era dilate'
'artist era tailed'
'strait are detail'
'strait are dilate'
'strait are tailed'
'strait ear detail'
'strait ear dilate'
'strait ear tailed'
'strait era detail'
'strait era dilate'
'strait era tailed'
'traits are detail'
'traits are dilate'
'traits are tailed'
'traits ear detail'
'traits ear dilate'
'traits ear tailed'
'traits era detail'
'traits era dilate'
'traits era tailed'
```

That syntax is for Python 3, where `map` returns an iterator. In Python 2 it returns a list, so you can get rid of the `list` call:

```
result = map(' '.join, product(*anagrams_list))
```

Or in modern versions of Python 3:

```
result = [*map(' '.join, product(*anagrams_list))]
```

If you're using Python 3 and you don't actually *need* a list, then just iterate over the map and process each phrase as it's generated:

```
for s in map(' '.join, product(*anagrams_list)):
    print(repr(s))
```